# Which has better performance jQuery class selector or document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I am trying to aim not to use `jQuery` and just rely on `JavaScript/ES6` codes. I think selecting elements can be achievable by using JavaScript's `document.queryselectorAll` and assign it to a variable.

Do you have any idea if there is a performance difference between `jquery class selector` vs `document.queryselectorAll`?

For example: `$(".list-wrap .list-item")` **vs** `var elementSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".list-wrap .list-item")`

I am also trying to find out that if I can do it purely in javascript without using `jQuery` it is faster because I am not using an additional library.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `$(".list-wrap .list-item")` is _not_ equal to `document.querySelectorAll(".list-wrap .list-item")`. The first returns an (jq-extended) `Array`, the last a `nodeList`.

Comment: @KooiInc Thank you for that. I was also trying to prove if it is possible to code and select elements by just using javascript/es6

Comment: [Ofcourse that's possible](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). JQuery basically is ES on steroids, initially designed to solve browser compatibility problems (as I recall based on the prototype.js library).

Comment: Since you have reactjs tag for this question I would advice not to use jQuery or querySelector(All) but use refs instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using selection query compatible to querySelectorAll you'll get the *same* performance.

jQuery is a smart and well designed library: it uses `querySelectorAll` internally if it's available in the browser.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?q=querySelectorAll&unscoped_q=querySelectorAll

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So I guess, pure javascript/es6 is not a full option

Comment: @redshot Note that JQ or any other library is a wrapper over JS to make our jobs easy. SO what a library can do, pure JS can also do. In fact, in theory, pure JS will be faster as there is no extra wrapping function and other checks a library adds to make it cross browser compatible

Comment: @redshot it is. It's OK to try to drop jquery. Many of jquery features are now in the browser, for example `querySelectorAll` if _very_ well supported (see https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for that insight. That is one my goals to this question if I can do it by using purely JS and if it has performance benefits.

Comment: @keul Thank you for the insight. I'm trying to use `JS` only for selecting element and just looping over it